# Is there any downside to removing Sys.PowerMgmt from all Roles?

Tags: proxmox

We use ProxMox (currently version 4.1-1) on a couple of servers here, and this morning I screwed up and shut down the entire system when I meant to shut down a VM. I'd like to avoid doing so in the future, and I'm willing to jump through extra hoops to shut down the system.

If I remove the 'Sys.PowerMgmt' from all Roles, are there any consequences BEYOND not being able to stop/start/restart/shutdown the node from the web UI?

If I need to shutdown the system, I'll simply ssh in or login at the console and issue 'shutdown -h now'.

Is there any downside to this plan that I'm unaware of? It looks like a good compromise to me, but I've long experience with not seeing all the flaws in my own plans.